# contenteditable doesn't recognize element

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a table that has a cell with **contenteditable**, what happens here is that when the user focus on the said cell. the text from `<strong class="cellData"></strong>` will be save in localStorage and when the user focused out the local storage variable will be use to display in the cell again if ever the user change it and did not click the check button to save it. so far I already achieve this however if I'm going to erase the data in the cell and focus out while it's blank, it doesn't display the original data from the local storage. I'm wondering what could be the problem here.

```
  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-dark table-hover table-sm" id="dataTable">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Size</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody  id="tableBody">
                        <?php 
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectResult)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td contenteditable class="tableCell numbersOnly" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 2)">
                            <input type="text" class="idInput" value="<?php echo $row['sizeID']; ?>" hidden>
                            <strong class="cellData"><?php echo $row['size']; ?></strong>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm editBtn" onclick="editItem($(this),'../assets/back-end-includes/update-size-script.php')">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                              </button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteProductModal">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                              </button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dataTable tbody td .editBtn").hide();
$('#dataTable tbody tr td:first-child').focus(function() {
  var originalValue = $(this).find('.cellData').text();
  var currentRowId = $(this).find(".idInput").val();
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  localStorage.setItem('originalValue', originalValue);
  localStorage.setItem('currentRowId', currentRowId);
  currentRow.find(".editBtn").show();
});
$('#dataTable tbody tr td:first-child').focusout(function() {  
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var originalValue = localStorage.getItem('originalValue');
    setTimeout(
  function()
  {
    currentRow.find(".editBtn").hide();
    currentRow.find(".cellData").html(originalValue);
  }, 150);
});  
</script>
```

hope someone can help, thanks in advance..